# What does double equal after colon means in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

so I found this code about pagination from server side, I understand everything except what does it do for this part, I know that the controller is watching currentPage, but there's no active variables and I don't know what does it mean to have double equal after a colon.

html & angular controller :

```js
app.controller("myController", function ($scope, Student ) {
 $scope.studentsPerPage = 5;
 $scope.currentPage = 0;
 $scope.range = function() {
  var rangeSize = 5;
  var ret = [];
  var start = $scope.currentPage;
  if (start > $scope.pageCount() - rangeSize) {
   start = $scope.pageCount() - rangeSize;
  }
  for (var i=start; i<start + rangeSize; i++) {
   ret.push(i);
  }
  return ret;
 };
 $scope.$watch("currentPage", function(newValue, oldValue) {
  $scope.pagedStudents = Student.get(newValue*$scope.studentsPerPage, $scope.studentsPerPage);
  $scope.total = Student.total();
 });
 $scope.prevPage = function() {
  if ($scope.currentPage > 0) {
   $scope.currentPage--;
  }
 };
 $scope.prevPageDisabled = function() {
  return $scope.currentPage === 0 ? "disabled" : "";
 };
 $scope.nextPage = function() {
  if ($scope.currentPage < $scope.pageCount()) {
   $scope.currentPage++;
  }
 };
 $scope.nextPageDisabled = function() {
  return $scope.currentPage >= ($scope.pageCount() -1) ? "disabled" : "";
 };
 $scope.pageCount = function() {
  return Math.ceil(Student.total() / $scope.studentsPerPage);
 };
 $scope.setPage = function(n) {
  $scope.currentPage = n;
 };
});
```

```html
<li data-ng-repeat="n in range()" data-ng-class="{active: n == currentPage}" data-ng-click="setPage(n)">
   <a href="#">{{n+1}}</a>
</li>
```

That is the whole and only controller, Student is a factory that I created for this taking a file from http get. The only point is I'm confused about the comparison after colon to watch the currentPage. thanks for anyone who answers, I appreciate it!

Comment: There is no such syntax as _"double equal after colon"_, `{active: n == currentPage }` is an object literal with an `active` property whose value is a boolean computed by evaluating the expression `n == currentPage` (which should use `===` but that is another topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for [`ngClass`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass).

> The result of the evaluation can be a string representing space delimited class names, an array, **or a map of class names to boolean values**. In the case of a map, the names of the properties whose values are truthy will be added as css classes to the element.

```
data-ng-class="{active: n == currentPage}"
```

What this does is add the class `active` to the element if the expression `n == currentPage` is truthy. You can add more class-expression pairs

```
data-ng-class="{active: n == currentPage, hidden: n == 0, answer: n == 42}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are confused about your binding `data-ng-class="{active: n == currentPage}"`? If so, `n` is the current index in your loop, and the binding is saying set the active class if `n` is equal to your `currentPage` variable.

Answer (score 0):

It is used to sync `n` with `currentPage`. Here's a breakdown :

> `data-ng-repeat="n in range()"` : let me loop through values in `range()`. For each iteration the variable I'll be using to refrence the currently looping value will be `n`
>
> `data-ng-class="{active: n == currentPage}"` : Now I want to know which is the active looping value. So I can use `n` and sync `currentPage` with it !. At the same time. I'll also use the `active` class to be applied to the current looping value of `n`

And the reason why you'd want to maintain this is because your'e then referencing `currentPage` in your controller